# DRUPAL views : Change Fate of filtered out nodes from drupal view filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

When filtering nodes using filter criteria from view (in my case exposed filter ), the excluded nodes are not displayed.
What i would like to achieve is still displaying these excluded nodes but differentely.

I imagine for example , displaying only the field teaser_image in case of `filtered-in` nodes and displaying only the field `back_flip_image` for the `filtered-out` nodes .

How could i do that ?

As a plan B, i would like to keep all remaining nodes `teaser_image` at the same position on the page whatever the exposed filter is clicked and use a default image to replace disappearing nodes

Answer (score 1):

Then remove that filter and move filtering logic to view template file.

Comment: good idea but is it that trivial ? this is ajax better exposed filter. How can i overwrite the filter ajax behaviour and display a field or another when a user click on an exposed filter ?

Comment: How about using contextual filters and custom made ajax form instead of exposed ajax filter?